# Should I use RecyclerView.VERTICAL instead of LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-lint

Running ./gradlew lint reports me an error which is confusing:

> 39: Must be one of: RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, RecyclerView.VERTICAL

In the source code:

```
    38 LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(rootView.getContext());
    39 linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    40 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    41 recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
```

Is there any reason I should change 39th line to

```
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
```

Comment: "Is there any reason I should change 39th line" – I guess, if you want to get rid of the (faulty) lint warning. They're the same value. In fact, `LinearLayoutManager`'s field is set to the `RecyclerView` field: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/LinearLayoutManager.java#52. Alternatively, you could just suppress the warning. If you put your cursor on that line, and hit alt-enter, there should be a "Suppress..." option.

Answer (score 11):

There is no difference in using the `LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL` or  `RecyclerView.VERTICAL`
because in `LinearLayoutManager` they are same.

```
public class LinearLayoutManager extends RecyclerView.LayoutManager implements
    ItemTouchHelper.ViewDropHandler, RecyclerView.SmoothScroller.ScrollVectorProvider {

private static final String TAG = "LinearLayoutManager";

static final boolean DEBUG = false;

public static final int HORIZONTAL = RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL;

public static final int VERTICAL = RecyclerView.VERTICAL;
```

As you can see in this code snippet from `LinearLayoutManager`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use this one for Vertical recycler view in android

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearlayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can provide `LayoutManager` from XML layout itself:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
```

Alternatively, you do this from Java code:

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
```